# ASP.NET MVC app is searching for view in a Controller folder

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I've a `BlogPostController` controller in the Controller folder with the following action methods. When you click on `Create` link in `<a asp-controller="BlogPost" asp-action="Create" asp-route-id="@item.BlogId">Create</a>` it correctly calls the Get method and after inserting a new value on Create.cshtml page it creates a record in SQL DB. But afterwards, it redirects the link to `http://localhost:59616/BlogPost/~BlogPost/Index.cshtml` that does not exist. It seems as if app is assuming the Views folder is inside Controller/PostBlog folder and tries to append the path `~/Views/BlogPost/Index.cshtml` to it. But there is no BlogPost folder under Controller folder as shown below. What may be wrong here?:

```
// GET: BlogPost/Create
public IActionResult Create()
{
     return View("~/Views/BlogPost/Create.cshtml");
}
    
// POST: BlogPost/Create.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("BlogId,Url")] Blog blog)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
     _context.Add(blog);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     return RedirectToAction("~/Views/BlogPost/Index.cshtml");
}
     return View("~/Views/BlogPost/Create.cshtml", blog);
}
```

**Project Folder Structure**:

[image]

**Note**: I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.0 and VS2015 on Windows 7

Comment: just try return View() and View("Index"). I am guessing the full path messed it up

Comment: I got it. Problem was that the was that the [RedirectToAction(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx)  method does not have any input parameter for view path. Instead I only had to provide the action name as in: `return RedirectToAction("Index");`

Comment: @Steve You are correct. Please see my comments and an MSDN link there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The issue was that that the [RedirectToAction(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx) method does not have any input parameter for view path. Instead I only had to provide the action name e.g: return RedirectToAction("Index");